# How can I write a function that prints different outputs for different values of parameters that are exogenously defined?

Tags: r, function, graph, parameters

I'm still a beginner with R so I apologize in advance if the question is too trivial, but I'm really stuck and I can't seem to find a solution.

I defined a function in *x* that has no parameters and I found its roots with "uniroot" (the function is strictly increasing so there is always one root). Now, I would like to introduce one parameter (let's say *a*) in the function and get R to print the different roots that the function assumes as *a* changes. For example, let's consider a simple function such as:

*F(x)= 2x + a*

I need R to print a table (maybe a matrix?) that looks something like this:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir9Vc.jpg)

where every value of the parameter is next to the root of the function (the text of the function in the first column is not actually needed).

The actual function that I'm using has to be solved by R every time, as it also contains the complementary error function (erfc) that I don't think I can make explicit. The final goal is to make a graph with the roots of the function on the Y axis and the value of the parameter on the X axis. I need the actual parameter to vary from  1/1000 to 1000, in this way:

1/1000, 1/999, 1/998, ..., 1/2, 1, 2, 3, ..., 1000

Basically the denominator decreases by 1 up to 1/1 and then the numerator starts increasing by 1.

I hope I was completely clear. Is there anyone that can help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function that returns another function to do this:

```
f <- function(a) function(x) 2 * x + a
sapply(-5:5, function(par) uniroot(f(par), c(-100, 100))$root)
 [1]  2.5  2.0  1.5  1.0  0.5  0.0 -0.5 -1.0 -1.5 -2.0 -2.5
```

Make a plot:

```
pars <- c(1/(1000:1), 2:1000)
root <- sapply(pars, function(par) uniroot(f(par), c(-600, 100))$root)
plot(pars, root)
```

[image]

You probably also want your x-axis to be log-scaled:

```
plot(log(pars), root)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.